# how do I create word/sentence keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to create either word or sentence (or both) keyboard shortcuts so that when you want to type a word, you can just do the shortcut and it pastes it into wherever you're typing? The idea is to be able to have shortcuts to paste boilerplate words or sentences into whatever application I'm typing in.

For example, my dad has trouble typing and say he typically types the word "photos" a lot. Is there a way to make it so that when he wants to type "photos", he can just do like Ctrl+P or some other shortcut so that "photos" is pasted into wherever he is typing?

This is not a question about MS Word or any text editing application, just in general. But if there are ways to customize MS Word or other apps, it would be nice to know how to do it :)

Comment: Look at the top answer for this question: http://superuser.com/questions/29254/automate-gui-tasks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Oliver implied, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Creating [keyboard shortcuts](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) and [sending keystrokes](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) are of the most basic functions of AHK. So, assigning <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to `photos` is as simple as:

```
^p::
Send, photos
return
```

Which translates to:

> If <kbd>P</kbd> is pressed while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is down, simulate the following keystrokes: `p`, `h`, `o`, `t`, `o`, and`s`.

Note that you can send uppercase letters without explicitly sending a preceding <kbd>Shift</kbd> key:

```
Send, PHOTOS
```

is equivalent to

```
Send, {Shift Down}photos{Shift Up}
```