# How to set keyboard shortcuts for skipping to beggining and end of line, and deleting a line in windows

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

So on macs, you can press option + E to skip to the end of the line, or option + A to skip to the beggining, or option + K to delete an entire line. I was wondering if it is possible to create similar shortcuts on windows 10. I'm trying to make it so that ctrl+A goes to the beggining of a line, ctrl+E goes to the end, and ctrl+K deletes an entire line. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Windows built-in Keyboard shortcuts here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

if you want to customize own word/sentence keyboard shortcuts, refer to this similar case:

how do I create word/sentence keyboard shortcuts

[how do I create word/sentence keyboard shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/391190/how-do-i-create-word-sentence-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: Would have been helpful if included what OP requested.